# Fetch and request to url from email body in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap, payload

How can I get and request to the link in 'a' tag like: "click here" from email body using NodeJS/JavaScript ?
In case the email body has more than one 'a' tag, how can I get an request to the url of the 'a' tag I want?

I did some research it was recommended to use npm imap, and I tried imap but still can't get the url of the 'a' tag from the email body. I am confused as to whether to use imap, imapflow, node-imap or is there another npm module that can help me. Also I was suggested to try get payload but I don't know how to implement it on JS and if it will work or not. I tried searching for keywords like: "extract url from email body in node js" or something like that but the results I got were not what I expected.

I hope to get help, I really appreciate that, Thank you for your time on my topic!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward to make fetch requests from certain a tags. I am attaching the code below.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const link = 'https://www.example.com';
//if this is your link make a fetch request to this link
fetch(link)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const aTag = doc.querySelector('a');
    const href = aTag.getAttribute('href');

    fetch(href)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => console.log(text));
  });
//end
```